# Angularjs Remove Objects With Empty Fields

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

If I have within my scope something a variable like so:

```
$scope.myListOLD = 
      [ 
        { title: "First title", content: "First content" }, 
        { title: "Second title", content: "" },
        { title: "Third title", content: "" }, 
        { title: "Fourth title", content: "Fourth content" }  
       ];
```

How could I create a new scope variable that removed any empty values on a specific field? (In this case content).

```
$scope.myListNEW = 
      [ 
        { title: "First title", content: "First content" }, 
        { title: "Fourth title", content: "Fourth content" }  
       ];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
function removeIfStringPropertyEmpty(arr, field) {
    return arr.filter(function(item) {
      return typeof item[field] === 'string' && item[field].length > 0;
    });
}

var $scope = {"myListOLD":[{"title":"First title","content":"First content"},{"title":"Second title","content":""},{"title":"Third title","content":""},{"title":"Fourth title","content":"Fourth content"}]};

$scope.myListNEW = removeIfStringPropertyEmpty($scope.myListOLD, 'content');

console.log($scope.myListNEW);
```

Comment: Works beautifully! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('homeCtrl', function ($scope) {
       $scope.myListOLD = 
      [ 
        { title: "First title", content: "First content" }, 
        { title: "Second title", content: "" },
        { title: "Third title", content: "" }, 
        { title: "Fourth title", content: "Fourth content" }  
       ];
  
  $scope.myListNEW = [];  
  angular.forEach($scope.myListOLD,function(value,key){
      if(value.content !== "")
        $scope.myListNEW.push(value);
    });
      console.log($scope.myListNEW);
  
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="homeCtrl">

</div>
```

You can use this

```
 angular.forEach($scope.myListOLD,function(value,key){
    if(value.content !== "")
      $scope.myListNEW.push(value);
  });
```